# Custom Listview clicking issue

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Custom Listview but i'm running into a weird issue when I click one item: it only responds when I click on the text itself, it doesn't work on the whole "rectangle"

this is my listelement.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:minHeight="20dip"
/>
```

and this is the java code:

```
public class TabFragment5 extends ListFragment {
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
String[] month ={
           "January                     ", 
           "February", 
           "March", 
           "April",
           "May", 
           "June", 
           "July", 
           "August",
           "September", 
           "October", 
           "November", 
           "December"
         };



         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.listelement,
            month);
          setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
         }

         @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag5_layout, container, false);
         }

         @Override
         public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Toast.makeText(
            getActivity(), 
            getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        }
```

Nevermind the silly program, i'm just running a tutorial for now. Any hints on how to make it work on the whole list item rectangle? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListFragment already has a ListView in it, so you may not need to inflate a layout from onCreateView unless you are making a custom layout that has a ListView inside it.  I imagine your problem is in your layout for tab_frag5_layout.  Whatever you are wrapping the ListView in is probably shrinking the width of the ListView.

Combining your onCreate and onCreateView into a onActivityCreated implementation worked for me.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{          
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(),
        R.layout.listelement,
        month);
  setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

}

Comment: "I imagine your problem is in your layout for tab_frag5_layout. Whatever you are wrapping the ListView in is probably shrinking the width of the ListView." 
THAT was the problem. I don't know how I haven't thought of that. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Add a view in there that fills the parent, since the only object in the list object is the TextView its the only thing you can press, try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it forces close. Logcat says I must supply a resource Id for a textview... (what does that mean?)

Comment: Hmm, didn't come up for me, try removing xmlns:android:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in the TextView and then clean the project and try again

Comment: Try removing the TextView and then adding it again using the gui supplied in eclipse, remember to add padding to the view